# Is encrypting source URL considered malicious practice for search engines?

Tags: seo

My client has articles rewritten and translated from some website. I show reference to the original articles at the end of the contents, but the URL is encrypted (it is decrypted by JavaScript so visitors can visit source articles when they click the link). Is it considered malicious by search engines? Can such practice lead to delisting from search engines?

Comment: What is the goal behind encrypting the sources?

Comment: Not quite sure. It's not my web-site. I was Just curious if Google cat enable sanctions for such practices

Comment: Pretty sure Google will be fine with it if I'm understanding the question correctly, but the idea still seems bizarre to me without more context.

Comment: Please post an example. It sounds like the site is perhaps _tracking_ the click (but "encrypted"?) and perhaps trying to make it nofollow(?), although Google is pretty good at processing JavaScript these days and there are better ways at making links nofollow.